# Website privileges in separate SQL table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm creating a website and I only want certain users to be granted the privilege of creating a post.

I have a table named `Accounts` where each user's basic information is stored (`Id, firstName, lastName, email`). Should I include a `createPrivilege` attribute in the `Accounts` table?

Or should I create a separate table named `Privileges` where I have the columns (`id, createPrivilege`) and the `Id` is a foreign key referencing the `Accounts` table's `Id` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If "createPrivilege" is an attribute of "Account", and there is only one instance of that attribute for any given entity, the common pattern is to have that as a column in the Account.

However, that approach quickly becomes very messy - you're likely to have many privileges, and adding new columns for each will make the "account" table very messy.

The most common way to model privileges is to introduce the concept of "role". A single user typically has several roles. A role might be "anonymous user", "authenticated user", "moderator", etc.

So, my recommendation would be to have a table with "account", a table called "role", and a join table "account_role" with foreign keys to both.